# Fetch form values from localStorage to SSJS script

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, rest-api, ssjs, form

I am trying to resolve an issue of a scenario in which two cloud pages are created, for example, Page A contains a form with multiple fields, while Page B contains SSJS code to send the data to the marketing cloud database. From Page A, I want to retrieve the form values on Page B.

As of right now, I am using the localStorage method to fetch the information on Page B. I am able to see the values under inspect element > Application > Local Storage, but I am unable to access them using SSJS. I am looking for a way to fix it or any other approach would also be helpful.

I have added the following script to Page A:

```
<script>
    function getValues() {
      //Fetching form values
      var customer_name = document.getElementById("Customer_Name").value;
      var company_name = document.getElementById("Company_Name").value;
      var EmailAddress = document.getElementById("EmailAddress").value;
      var Product_Name1 = document.getElementById("Product_Name1").value;
      var Product_Quantity1 =
        document.getElementById("Product_Quantity1").value;
      var Customization1 = document.getElementById("Customization1").value;
      var Product_Name2 = document.getElementById("Product_Name2").value;
      var Product_Quantity2 =
        document.getElementById("Product_Quantity2").value;
      var Customization2 = document.getElementById("Customization2").value;

      //Saving the values in local storage
      localStorage.setItem("Customer_Name", customer_name);
      localStorage.setItem("Company_Name", company_name);
      localStorage.setItem("EmailAddress", EmailAddress);
      localStorage.setItem("Product_Name1", Product_Name1); 
      localStorage.setItem("Product_Quantity1", Product_Quantity1);
      localStorage.setItem("Customization1", Customization1);
      localStorage.setItem("Product_Name2", Product_Name2);
      localStorage.setItem("Product_Quantity2", Product_Quantity2);
      localStorage.setItem("Customization2", Customization2); 
    }
</script>
```

The script I added to Page B is below:

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");

  try {
    var accessToken = "";
    var authEndpoint = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx";
    var client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var account_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    var grant_type = "client_credentials";

    //auth
    var url =
      "https://" + authEndpoint + ".auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
    var contentType = "application/json";
    var payload = '{"grant_type":"' + grant_type + '",';
    payload += '"client_id":"' + client_id + '",';
    payload += '"client_secret":"' + client_secret + '",';
    payload += '"account_id":"' + account_id + '"}';

    // create token
    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
    var statusCode = accessTokenResult["StatusCode"];
    var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
    var resultCode = accessTokenResult.StatusCode;
    accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;
    Write("<br><br> Access Token = " + accessToken + "<br><br>");

    // Debug info below
    Write("Status Code: " + resultCode + "<br><br>");
    if (resultCode === 200) {
      // Another API call here
      var restURL = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).rest_instance_url;
      Write("Rest URL = " + restURL + "<br><br>");

      //Fetching the value from local storage
      // Issue is occurring in this block
      var customer_name = localStorage.getItem("Customer_Name");
      var company_name = localStorage.getItem("Company_Name");
      var EmailAddress = localStorage.getItem("EmailAddress");
      var Product_Name1 = localStorage.getItem("Product_Name1");
      var Product_Quantity1 = localStorage.getItem("Product_Quantity1");
      var Customization1 = localStorage.getItem("Customization1");
      var Product_Name2 = localStorage.getItem("Product_Name2");
      var Product_Quantity2 = localStorage.getItem("Product_Quantity2");
      var Customization2 = localStorage.getItem("Customization2");

      Write("Customer_Name = " + customer_name + "<br><br>");
      Write("Company_Name = " + company_name + "<br><br>");
      Write("EmailAddress = " + EmailAddress + "<br><br>");
      Write("Product_Name1 = " + Product_Name1 + "<br><br>");
      Write("Product_Quantity1 = " + Product_Quantity1 + "<br><br>");
      Write("Customization1 = " + Customization1 + "<br><br>");
      Write("Product_Name2 = " + Product_Name2 + "<br><br>");
      Write("Product_Quantity2 = " + Product_Quantity2 + "<br><br>");
      Write("Customization2 = " + Customization2 + "<br><be>");
      
      // End of issue block

      var restPayload = '{"To": {';
      restPayload += '"Address": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
      restPayload += '"SubscriberKey": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
      restPayload += '"ContactAttributes": {';
      restPayload += '"SubscriberAttributes": {';
      restPayload += '"SubscriberKey": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
      restPayload += '"EmailAddress": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
      restPayload += '"Customer Name": "' + customer_name + '",';
      restPayload += '"Company Name": "' + company_name + '",';
      restPayload += '"Product_Name1": "' + Product_Name1 + '",';
      restPayload += '"Product_Quantity1": ' + Product_Quantity1 + ",";
      restPayload += '"Customization1": "' + Customization1 + '",';
      restPayload += '"Product_Name2": "' + Product_Name2 + '",';
      restPayload += '"Product_Quantity2": ' + Product_Quantity2 + ",";
      restPayload += '"Customization2": "' + Customization2 + '"'';
      restPayload += "}}}}";

      Write("<br><br>Payload: " + restPayload);

      var apiRoute, bearerToken;

      apiRoute =
        restURL + "messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:xxxxxx/send";

      bearerToken = "Bearer " + accessToken;

      var headerName = "Authorization";
      var headerValue = bearerToken;

      var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(apiRoute);
      req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
      req.retries = 2;
      req.continueOnError = true;
      req.contentType = "application/json";
      req.method = "POST";
      req.setHeader(headerName, headerValue);
      req.postData = restPayload;

      var resp = req.send();

      //Parsing the Response
      var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
      var headers = resp.header;
      var contentTypes = resp.contentType;
      var statuss = resp.returnStatus;

      Write("<br><br>resultJSON: " + Stringify(resultJSON));
      Write("<br><br>headers: " + Stringify(headers));
      Write("<br><br>contentTypes: " + Stringify(contentTypes));
      Write("<br><br>statuss: " + Stringify(statuss));

      var statusCode = resp.statusCode;
      if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 201) {
        status = "success";
        Write("<br><br>Result Status: " + Stringify(statusCode));
        Write("<br><br>Result Content: " + Stringify(resultJSON));
        Write("<br><br><b>Information is successfully submitted</b>");
      } else {
        status = "Error code: " + statusCode;
        Write("<br><br>Result Status: " + Stringify(statusCode));
        Write("<br><br>Result Content: " + Stringify(resultJSON));
        Write(
          "<br><br><b>An error occurred while submitting the information.</b>"
        );
      }
    } else {
      // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false
      Write(
        "Result Code is " +
          resultCode +
          ". Please check the code again <br><br>"
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Write("<br><br> Error: " + Stringify(e));
    Write("<br><br> Error name: " + Stringify(e.name));
    Write("<br><br> Error message: " + Stringify(e.message));
  }
</script>
```

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is not the right approach for this solution. Instead, simply take your SSJS code and host it on a JSON code resource page. Then, make an AJAX request to your code resource from the form on submission while passing the form data in the payload.